# Another way to show $\nabla u =0$ a.e. on $u=0$ for $u\in H^1(\Omega)$

Tags: real-analysis, sobolev-spaces

This is an exercise on Evans PDE book, Ch5. It provides another way to prove $\nabla u =0$ a.e. on $u=0$ for $u\in H^1(\Omega)$ then the one in Evans & Griapy's book.

The statement is as following. Choose $\phi$ smooth on $R$ such that $\phi(z)=z$ if $|z|<1$ and $|\phi(z)|\leq |z|$ for all $z\in R$. Moreover, $\phi$ is constant if $|z|>1+\delta$ for some $\delta>0$. We also require that $\phi'$ is bounded.

Then given any $u\in H^1(\Omega)$ we define $u_\epsilon:=\epsilon \phi (u/\epsilon)$ and it is easy to verify that $u_\epsilon$ is uniformly bounded in $H^1$ and hence we have subsequence convergence weakly to some $u$.

It is also very quick to prove that $u_\epsilon\to 0$ weakly in $L^2$. However, I got stack at the point on how to prove $\nabla u_\epsilon\to 0$ weakly in $L^2$ as well. here is what I tried: for any $g\in L^2(\Omega)$,
$$\lim_\epsilon \int_\Omega \partial_i u_\epsilon \,\,g dx = \lim_\epsilon \int_\Omega \partial_i \phi'(u/\epsilon)\partial_i u \,\,\,g dx=  \int_\Omega \lim_\epsilon\partial_i \phi'(u/\epsilon)\partial_i u \,\,\,g dx = \int_{\{u=0\}}\partial_i u\,\,gdx$$
But I can not prove the limit is finally $0$... Any help would be very welcome!

Comment: Take $g$ smooth with compact support in $\Omega$; integrate by parts the first integral; use $u_\epsilon\to0$ w-$L^2$ to show the limit is $0$. Then by density the last integral vanishes for all $g$ in $L^2$

Comment: Actually, the density argument is really bother me.... please come to this post to help! Thx! http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/975820/the-question-regrading-to-density-argument-in-analysis